# Advanced ID3 tag inter-field processing

Tags: batch, mp3, id3

I have a bunch of MP3s with the same generic album "_misc". In the `comment` field, the files also have the real album name stored using the pattern `album[REAL_ALBUM_NAME]`. There may or may not be other text in the comment field before and after the `album` declaration.

I would like to automatically extract the real album name for each of these MP3s and place it in the `album` field (overwriting "_misc") using a batch/automated process. How can I do this? I can access the files with Windows, OS X, or Ubuntu (running as a live CD/DVD).

Comment: mp3tag's tag to filename function may do this, but this is a *little* trickier than any scenario I've done this with - IE, I need to test this before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html) indeed does this. Use **Tag -> Tag**. Set the `ALBUM` field to `$regexp(%comment%,album\[(.*)\],\1)`. (I haven't tested this, but it should work.)

Edit: Click `Convert->Actions` and set the type to Format Value. The regexp is `$regexp(%comment%,'^.*album\[([^\]]+)\].*$',$1)` – note the `.*` at the beginning and end of the expression to avoid matching other text in the comment field, and you use `$1` to reference the match. ([Source](http://forums.mp3tag.de/index.php?showtopic=16466&st=0&gopid=67695&#entry67695))

Comment: Close! I made a slight correction. Thanks pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it for me. I hadn't used the `$regexp` function before, but I do think MP3Tag is an excellent tool.